# How to break rest script in $.each

Tags: jquery

#### html

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

#### script

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();

    console.log(html);

    if (parseInt(html) === 2) {
        return false;
    }
});

console.log(123);
```

If I use normal loop function like `for` or `while`, and use `return false` in some condition, the script will be break, I won't see the result 123, `$.each` is an `Anonymous functions`, if I use `return false` it's only break the each loop inside, is there any skill to break the rest script inside the `$.each`?

I know I can do something as below, but feel it's ugly

```
var stop = false;

$('div').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();

    console.log(html);

    if (parseInt(html) === 2) {
        stop = true;
        return false;
    }
});

if (stop === true) {
    return false;
}

console.log(123);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do is unclear to me....

Comment: `return false` will break the loop

Comment: Proof -> **http://jsfiddle.net/w8fp9qke/**

Comment: I know return false will break loop in `$.each`, but you can still see `123`, I want to stop all stuff

Comment: Are you trying to return something from an outer function we can't see?

Comment: It's just a validation code to check something by `$.each`, so if something wrong, I need to stop whole script and alert, that's all

Comment: can use `filter()` combined with `length` to make it a bit cleaner looking

Comment: That makes no sense, you can't stop the "whole script", you place the code in conditions and work with that

Comment: @adeneo Use a variable can make that happened, just want to know any trick can do the same thing

Comment: Sorry, I mean the rest script, not the script from beginning~

Comment: This question made absolutely no sense to me!

Comment: @BenjaminPaul Could you explain why? jQuery genius James Padolsey talk many skills to solve many issue not in normal, for example http://goo.gl/UThf7k, why my issue called no sense?

Comment: Even your last comment makes no sense to me, your english is broken. JQuery genius? Your question is badly written and does not clearly explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for the bad English to arrogant British, is stackoverflow  only for American or British? Let's try to speak in Chinese, can you?

Comment: @Chan: The common language of SO is English and our Chinese is probably a *lot* worse than your English. Please do accept that the question may not be as clearly worded as it could be. It took me some time to figure out what you actually meant (answer below), but even now I am not sure it is what you were after :)

Comment: "Please do accept that the question may not be as clearly worded as it could be" << @Chan, I have no problem with your English not being perfect however you made little or no attempt at making your question easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the people who just tolerant my bad English and kindly answer my question like @TrueBlueAussie, thanks a lot

Comment: @BenjaminPaul, I hope you can solve the issue regards how my question stupid is, I don't think it an non-sense question, even it doesn't have right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really testing for the existance of a value, so use a `filter` and check the returned length:

```
if ($('div').filter(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    console.log(html);
    return (parseInt(html) === 2);
}).length)
{
    return;
}
console.log(123);
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w8fp9qke/2/

You can reduce it to this if you want smaller code:

```
if ($('div').filter(function() {
    return ~~$(this).html() === 2;
}).length){
    return;
}
console.log(123);
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w8fp9qke/3/

`~~` is a nice shortcut converter for a string to an int value.